# Google Maps url parameters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

In url requests for Google Maps, the center of the domain has to be defined:

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=10.027489,51.229248&size=650x650&zoom=14&sensor=false"

Even when I play with zoom or size, I don't get the exact map that I want. Is there a way to define the southwest and northeast corners of the domain ? Or any other way to better define a domain ?

Comment: What is the "exact map you want"? Zoom levels in google maps are discrete, zoom=14 is twice the scale of zoom=13.  By changing size, zoom and center, you should be able to cover a specific geographic area, but if you have a fixed size, you can't.

Comment: I have a fixed size...

Comment: If you have a fixed size you can't specify an arbitrary bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `visible` parameter to specify the 2 opposite corners of a rectangular region, and the map will automatically adjust center and zoom to fit that region.

See [Implicit Positioning of the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#ImplicitPositioning) (there's an example there).