# How to set fitbound/ max zoom from boundary location by google static map api

Tags: google-maps-static-api, fitbounds

I am beginner to using google map api.
my work is to get image from specific crop plant boundary, and do image processing for their vegetation index. But each plant field have different area size so I need to adjust the zoom level to cover all area.

I have learned how to use url for requesting the map,
but I can't find how to set the fitbound, or maximize the zoom level while showing all point from request boundary location. 
Please give me any advice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBklK.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps url parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352477/google-maps-url-parameters)